# Present value of varying annuities

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I need help with the following questions. In order to answer these questions, I am only allowed to use two of the tables of values for $\ddot a_n , \bar a_n$ (continuous annuity) and   $(I \ddot a)_n$ from n=1,...,30 and i=3%.

(h) Given an effective annual rate of 3%, calculate the present value at time 0 of a 15-year arithmetically increasing annuity immediate whereby the first annual payment is 2,452
and subsequent annual increment is 450.

$PV_0 = 2002 \ddot a_{15} + 450 (I \ddot a)_{15}$

$ = 2002*12.29607 + 450*91.60627$

=$65,839.55

(i) Consider a stream of 30-year continuous cash flows with a payment rate of 404t during year t. For instance, the payment rate during year 5 is $2,020. Calculate its present value
at time 0 given an effective annual rate of 3%.

$PV_0 = 404(I \bar a)_{30} + 404 \bar a_{30}$

$= 404(I \ddot a)_{30}* \frac{d}{\delta} + 404 \bar a_{30}$

$=404*268.7906* \frac {1-(1.03)^{-1}}{ln(1.03)} +404*19.893$

=$115,038.96

Any help is appreciated, especially for i) as I'm not too sure about that question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to write out the cash flows and set up the equation of value.

For (h), an increasing annuity-**immediate** has the first payment of $2452$ at time $t = 1$, so the equation of value is $$PV = 2452 v + 2902 v^2 + \cdots + 8752 v^{15}$$ where $v = 1/(1+i)$ and $i = 0.03$.  Using your line of reasoning, this would be $$PV = 2002(v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{15}) + 450(v + 2v^2 + 3v^3 + \cdots 15v^{15}).$$  Therefore, the correct equation in actuarial notation would need to be $$PV = v\left(2002 \ddot a_{\overline{15}\rceil i} + 450 (I \ddot a)_{\overline{15}\rceil i}\right).$$

For (i), the equation of value is more difficult to express.  Consider the cash flow in year $t$ alone.  This corresponds to 
$$404t {\bar a}_{\overline{1} \rceil i}$$
before discounting for the year in which the payment is made.  In other words, we are only taking the present value of the payments in year $t$ to time $t-1$.  Now if we discount for the year, this is an extra factor of $v^{t-1}$.  So the cash flow is 
$$PV = 404 {\bar a}_{\overline{1}\rceil i} + 808 v {\bar a}_{\overline{1}\rceil i} + \cdots + 12120 v^{29} {\bar a}_{\overline{1}\rceil i}.$$  Factoring, we get $$PV = 404 {\bar a}_{\overline{1}\rceil i} \left( 1 + 2v + 3v^2 + \cdots + 30v^{29} \right) = 404 {\bar a}_{\overline{1}\rceil i} (I\ddot a)_{\overline{30}\rceil i}.$$

Comment: Why do you need to multiply by v for h)?

Comment: @Spartasporter Because the first payment is not at time $t = 0$.  The first payment occurs at the **end** of the first year of the annuity.  This is what is meant by annuity-**immediate** rather than annuity-**due**.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. For i) why is it $\bar a_1$ ? Shouldn't it be $\bar a_{30}$ ?

Comment: @Spartasporter The term $\bar a_{\overline{1}\rceil i}$ is the present value of $1$ paid continuously for a $1$ year term, during which time the payment is level.  Then at each integer year, you take this present value as the equivalent amount paid at the beginning of each year.  The payments are continuous in frequency, but **discrete** in value.  So for the first year, payments are made at a continuous rate of $404$ per year, but next year, they are made at a continuous rate of $808$ per year.

Comment: So for i), would you express the present value as being $(\bar I \bar a)_{30}$ and then you convert it in terms of the allowed annuity functions?

Comment: @Spartasporter No.  $(\bar I \bar a)_{\overline{30}\rceil i}$ is actuarial notation for a **continuously increasing continuous annuity**, meaning the payment function is completely continuous over time.  The correct notation is $(I \bar a)_{\overline{30}\rceil i}$, but you don't have this in your table, which is why I expressed it in terms of symbols you **did** have.  In general, $$(I \bar a)_{\overline{n}\rceil i} = \bar a_{\overline{1}\rceil i} (I\ddot a)_{\overline{n}\rceil i}.$$  The formal proof of this is left to you as an exercise but the equation of value I wrote should show you why.

Comment: To make it absolutely clear, when both the $I$ and the $a$ have bars over them, then for example, at time $0.5$, the rate of payment is $0.5$, and at time $2.1$, the rate of payment is $2.1$.  But if only the $a$ has a bar over it, then at times $0$ through $1$, the rate of payment is $1$--it is *level* throughout the first year.  Then at times $1$ through $2$, the rate of payment is $2$.

Comment: Oh ok. I get it now. Thanks for the clarification